# In general, is 5V CMOS compatible with 5V TTL?

Tags: digital-logic

Can you in general interface the two without issue?

Comment: Do you mean something like 74HCxxx and 74LSxxx or 74xx?  OR do you mean 74HCxxx and 74HCTxxx?

Comment: See pages 18–23 of [HCMOS Design Considerations](https://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/scla007).

Answer (score 2):

No, **in general** you can not interface generic "5V CMOS" with generic "5V TTL".

For any given two devices you must, as a minimum, make sure that the worst-case output voltages of the driver satisfy the worst-case input voltage requirements of the receiver. In other words, compare \$V_{OH}\$ to \$V_{IH}\$ and compare \$V_{OL}\$ to \$V_{IL}\$. Just in case this is an exam/homework question I'll leave a few details up to you.

Answer (score 1):

5V HCMOS output can drive 5V TTL without a problem.

5V TTL can't drive HCMOS because doesn't have adequate Vo(h) (2.4V) to meet HCMOS threshold of 2/3 Vcc (3.33V). The HC**T** variant of HCMOS has lower Vi(h) (2.0V) that is compatible with TTL.

This chart compares the Vo(l)/(h) and Vi(l)/(h) for common logic families.

[image]
From here: https://www.jsykora.info/2014/05/logic-voltage-levels/

Answer (score 0):

For 74HC family the Rout is ~ 50 Ohms +/- 25%

For TTL each family has a
Different \$I_{IL}\$ low input current and safe margin \$V_{IL} ~max \$ which is below the actual threshold of two \$V_{BE}\$ drops or 1.3V. Check specs and see if Ohm’s Law satisfied the load and threshold voltage.